# ipython %bookmark error: quotes don't fix this

Tags: ipython, ipython-magic

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't find an answer.

`%bookmark dl 'C:/Users/user1/Downloads'` works, but %bookmark md `'C:/Users/user1/my documents'` doesn't work, throwing error:

"UsageError: %bookmark: too many arguments"

How to fix this?

Comment: It works for me. Do you definitely have the 'quotes' around the path?

Comment: Yes I definitely have the quotes. That's why I find it inexplicable.

Answer (score 0):

Using "double-quotes" fixed it for me.
Have a go with:   %bookmark md "C:/Users/user1/my documents"